# Best way to determine proper downcast

Tags: java, inheritance, downcast

I have an abstract superclass called `C` and multiple subclasses of it: `SubC1, SubC2, ...` Now I have a collection of the superclass `C` and I want to iterate over it, but do something different depending on which subclass it is. Here is the pseudo-code:

```
abstract class C{}
class SubC1 extends C{}
class SubC2 extends C{}

...

for(C c : cs){
    if(c is a SubC1){
    //do one thing
    }
    if(c is a SubC2){ 
    //do another
    }
}
```

However Im not really sure how to set up the if conditionals. My first thought was to use `instanceof` but then I realized that it doesnt work for downcasts. Then I considered adding a `String` field to `C` and make each subclass define it and base my conditionals around that, but that seems clunky. I also considered trying to use process of elimination by forcing a downcast and catching the `ClassCastExceptions`, but that is also clunky and seems kinda dangerous. So how can I get what I want without having stupid code?

Edit: I forgot to add that it would not make sense for me to add a `doSomething()` function in C and just override it.

Edit 2: For some reason I thought doing `c instanceof SubC1` caused a compiler error. Now that I realize it didnt I have my answer.

Comment: This is what polymorphism is for.  Define an abstract method in the base class, and then put the specific behaviours in overrides in each subclass.

Comment: Take a look on this: http://www.artima.com/interfacedesign/PreferPoly.html

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I edited my question in response to your comment.

Answer (score 3):

Have an abstract method `doSomething` in `C` and override it in all of your subclasses, then call `C#doSomething`

Comment: I forgot to add, I cant really do that. It wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: In that case you're stuck with `if(c instanceof SubC1) { SubC1 subc1 = (SubC1)c; }`

Comment: Oh... for some reason I thought that caused a compiler error. Nevermind then.

Comment: Nope, it might cause a runtime error if `c` isn't a `SubC1`, but that's what the `if(c instanceof SubC1)` guard is for